# django two foreign keys unique record

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I have three django models:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    itemid = models.IntegerField(default=0, unique=True)

class Region(models.Model):
    regionid = models.IntegerField(default=0, unique=True)

class Price(models.Model):
    regionid = models.ForeignKey(Region)
    itemid = models.ForeignKey(Item)
```

Now my issue is this:

I need to have Price be unique for the Item and Region combination (e.g. itemid = 1 & regionid = a therefore there can only be one Price that can have foreign keys of itemid = 1 and regionid = a).

Is there any way to enforce that relationship?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at [unique together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.unique_together)! It may solve your issue.

Comment: so I'd add something like this to the end of my Price class? 
class Meta:
unique_together = ("regionid", "itemid")?

Answer (score 0):

Django does not yet support compound indicies. The accepted solution is to register a post_syncdb signal handler -- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/signals/#post-syncdb

Here's the template (you'll need to fill in the appropriate details):

```
from django.db import connection
from django.db.models.signals import post_syncdb
def callback(sender, **kwargs):
    cur = connection.cursor()
    cur.execute('CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ...')

post_syncdb.connect(callback, sender=app.models)
```

Comment: I'm sorry you'll have to hand hold me a little bit more. I am very new to python and django - I've read over the link you've provided but still don't get it. Where would I put that? How would I word unique index?

Comment: I stand corrected -- Alvaro has it right. Django now has 'unique together' (and looks like they've had it for awhile)